# spring-cloud-stream security protocol configuration not applied

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to configure the security protocol of the Kafka binder. As documented in the spring-cloud-stream reference the security.protocol property should exist in the spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration hierarchy but this configuration is not being applied.
I am getting the following warning: 
 **

> WARN 17375 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig
>   : The configuration 'security' was supplied but isn't a known config.

**

My yaml snippet:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost
          defaultBrokerPort: 9092
          zkNodes: localhost
          defaultZkPort: 2181
          minPartitionCount: 2
          replicationFactor: 1
          autoCreateTopics: true
          autoAddPartitions: true
          headers: type,message_id
          requiredAcks: 1
          configuration:
            security:
              protocol: SSL
```

I tried to debug the loading of the properties and it looks like that this property is being split and the configuration map is something like: {"security" : {"protocol" : "SSL"}} instead of {"security.protocol" : "SSL"}.
I also tried to change the yaml file to: 
 
`configuration:
   security.protocol: SSL` 
But there was no difference.

**EDIT:** The Spring Cloud Stream version is Chelsea.SR2 and the Spring Boot version is 1.5.4.RELEASE.

Comment: What version of Spring Cloud Stream and Spring Boot are you using ?

Comment: spring boot 1.5.4.RELEASE. spring cloud stream Chelsea.SR2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar issue has been reported here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/129.

We're investigating whether this is an issue in Spring Cloud Stream or Spring Boot.

Comment: I used the workaround that was suggested in the issue and it worked. Thanks!